# trying to add two querySelectorAll items to a forEach loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach

I've been trying to apply the newText.innerText to the oldText.innerText and it only takes the last element in the newText and applies it to all the oldText I've tried to add the index and the array to the loop and run the code after adding them as a number counter but it still wouldn't work, I've also tried to define a new element and assign the newText value to it but still it didn't work

```
      <body>
        <h3 class="oldText">oldText</h3>
        <h3 class="oldText">oldText</h3>
        <h3 class="oldText">oldText</h3>
        <h3 class="oldText">oldText</h3>
        <h3 class="oldText">oldText</h3>
    
        <h3 class="newText">newText1</h3>
        <h3 class="newText">newText2</h3>
        <h3 class="newText">newText3</h3>
        <h3 class="newText">newText4</h3>
        <h3 class="newText">newText5</h3>
        
<script> 

    var oldText = document.querySelectorAll('.oldText')
    var newText = document.querySelectorAll('.newText')
    oldText.forEach((oldT) => {
      newText.forEach((newT) => {
      oldT.innerText = newT.innerText
      })
    })

</script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

while I'm trying to make the oldText have the same innerText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a foreach loop, you can simply use a for loop like this:

```
var oldText = document.querySelectorAll('.oldText')
var newText = document.querySelectorAll('.newText')
for (var i = 0; i < oldText.length; i++){
  oldText[i].innerText = newText[i].innerText;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot for this solution it was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a nested loop. Just loop through each `oldText` element and assign its `.innerText` to the `.innerText` of the corresponding `newText` element:

```
var oldText = document.querySelectorAll('.oldText')
var newText = document.querySelectorAll('.newText')
oldText.forEach((oldT, i) => {
  oldT.innerText = newText[i].innerText
})
```

`i` is the index into the `newText` array.

Comment: thanks alot for this solution it was really helpful